How to trigger Webhook with first message using parameters in intents
Dialogflow CX asks for the name and the user should state it. The input is saved in a parameter and then sent via a webhook to Cloud Functions, which processes the value. When I send the message for the first time, nothing happens. The second time, the webhook is then triggered. I can't find a solution to this.
[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Z44h7k4m.png)
There is nothing in my log. This is only triggered with the 2nd message
